# Is libgit2 safe during power loss?

Tags: libgit2

Given a use case where you append objects to the object store, and update a ref to point to a new commit, is libgit2 safe, where safe is defined as one of the following outcomes:

- Power is lost before the ref is updated, no "visible" changes to the head of the repository.
- Power is lost after the ref is updated, head points to the new commit and all data is available.

The key points would be at what point does libgit2 guarantee the data is flushed to the disk. Before the ref is updated, do we guarantee that the data in the object database is flushed to disk?

In other words: In what cases could the ref be updated, but the object store has not persisted the data?

UPDATE: I found that libgit2 is now implementing optional support for fsync https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/4030 which means that all loose object writes (appends) should be on disk before the ref is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody guarantees you that anything gets written to a disk when you loose power. There are only two solutions for this problem: disable write cache or use UPS. At least a battery to flush the RAID controller cache.

Comment: Sure, that's reasonable. But, given that your storage is not faulty and respects fsync, it should be possible to ensure all objects are fsynced before the ref is updated? Then the next question is does libgit2 do this?

Comment: That is interesting, thanks. My question specifically resides with how `libgit2` is implemented though.